# How to assign the value to the variable and use it on another action in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Kendogrid with filters, paging etc. On any action applied on the grid like paging, filtering etc the following action was called.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Returns the Manager List  numbers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">DataSourceRequest</param>
        /// <returns>JSON object</returns>
        public ActionResult GetCases([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
           //some code
        }
```

There is also the textbox and a button in my View. When I enter the any number in TextBox then a Jquery is called and a AJAX call is performed which call the different action method in same controller.

**Now my question is that how can I got the " [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request " in this [SelectRecords] action with having earlier values (values which are set when filter is applied).**

**Note:** Here in SelectRecords I got Null Values not the values which are set on Filter.

```
public ActionResult SelectRecords(Int32 noOfRecords, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
           //Some code
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DataSourceRequest` object `request` changes each time whenever a request is made.

To have the same values of request you have to send the same request.

you might find an example of the request below
[image] 
use the same argument in calling the `SelectRecords` method from the client side and you will start getting the same `request` object

Comment: I can't use the same argument. I want to have the values when I click on the button click. How can I store the value of DataSourceRequest to a variable and use it on SelectRecords action on button click.

Comment: you must be sending values to the `GetManagerAssignUnresolvedCases` method save the result in hidden fields at client side, manipulate it just before calling the `SelectRecord` method and then call it

Comment: The Hidden fields record only 1 record nut the DataSourceRequest contains the List (also contains nested list). Is there any other alternative.

Comment: If your method is so loose that it depends on collections that it is better to store the previous `DataSourceRequest` in objects such as session and then use session to retrieve the past values

Comment: also if you want to save it only on filtering then make session conditionally

Comment: Actually it is a large application and the use of session is limited. I can't use the session. Is there is any Viewstate like equivelent thing in MVC.

Comment: there is not but a way to achieve the functionality was explained by me earlier for better understanding go [here] http://forums.asp.net/t/1729392.aspx?Is%20there%20any%20viewstate%20to%20store%20some%20data%20in%20mvc3%20view